# OpenCV - DLL missing, but it's not?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying just a basic program with OpenCV with the following code:

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

int main()
{
    IplImage* newImg;
    newImg = cvLoadImage("~/apple.bmp", 1);
    cvNamedWindow("Window", 1);
    cvShowImage("Window", newImg);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvDestroyWindow("Window");
    cvReleaseImage(&newImg);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get

> The program can't start because
>   libcxcore200.dll is missing from your
>   computer.  Try reinstalling the
>   program to fix this problem.

However, I can see this DLL.  It exists.  I have added the following to the input dependencies for my linker

> C:\OpenCV2.0\lib\libcv200.dll.a
>   C:\OpenCV2.0\lib\libcvaux200.dll.a
>   C:\OpenCV2.0\lib\libcxcore200.dll.a
>   C:\OpenCV2.0\lib\libhighgui200.dll.a

What gives? I'm using visual studio 2008.

When I link the .dll files instead of .dll.a files, I get

> fatal error LNK1107:invalid or corrupt
>   file: cannot read at 0x3F8
>   libcv200.dll

Answer (score 26):

Here's how I resolved it.

1. Fetched MSVC 2010 express edition.
2. Fetched Win 32 OpenCV 2.2 binaries and installed in default location.
3. Created new project.
4. Project setup

   Project -> OpenCV_Helloworld Properties...Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories

   Include Directories... add: `C:\OpenCV2.2\include\;`

   Library Directories... add: `C:\OpenCV2.2\lib;C:\OpenCV2.2\bin;`

   Source Directories... add:

   ```
    C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\calib3d\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\contrib\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\core\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\features2d\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\flann\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\gpu\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\gpu\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\highgui\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\imgproc\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\legacy\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\ml\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\objdetect\src;C:\OpenCV2.2\modules\video\src;
   ```

   Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies...

   For Debug Builds... add:

   ```
    opencv_calib3d220d.lib;opencv_contrib220d.lib;opencv_core220d.lib;opencv_features2d220d.lib;opencv_ffmpeg220d.lib;opencv_flann220d.lib;opencv_gpu220d.lib;opencv_highgui220d.lib;opencv_imgproc220d.lib;opencv_legacy220d.lib;opencv_ml220d.lib;opencv_objdetect220d.lib;opencv_video220d.lib;
   ```

I then ran into the problem you described when running the exe in debug mode. The final step is to select:

Linker -> General ... Set 'Use Library Dependency Inputs' to 'Yes'

Comment: after doing this, problem persisted. Then I restarted MS Visual Studio 2010 and then it worked.

Answer (score 19):

Just add `C:\OpenCV2.0\bin` into your **PATH** environment variable.

Or, when you install OpenCV, choose the option: `Add OpenCV to the system PATH for current user`, which is not default one.

Comment: It's already in my path.  I did notice this option when installing and I selected it.

Comment: @charles, strange enough then, I couldn't reproduce your errors, your example codes running fine here. only I am using mingw32-gcc instead of visual studio 2008 c++ compiler.

Comment: Interesting.  I really don't feel that this should be giving me this error, as it doesn't seem to be a common issue.  Confusing.

Comment: @charles, and I just tried both OpenCV 2.0 and 2.1, both are working, so not OpenCV version issue either.

Comment: @charles, its because of those .dll in `OpenCV2.0\bin` directory are compiled with 32 bit

Comment: I meant VC++ compiler, not VC++ IDE btw.

Comment: I would like to add that after adding the OpenCV bin folder to the system path it might not update immediately. The permanent solution is to reboot but if you'd rather finish something before a full reboot you can open visual studio as an administrator and it will recognize the new changes to the PATH.

Answer (score 15):

After adding the "PATH", for my Windows 7, I need to reboot it, to get it work.

Comment: Finaly, restarting helped me.

Comment: usually just log-out, log-in without rebooting is enough

Comment: visual studio 2015 opencv 3.10 missing dll problem solved after a restart :)

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that if you don't feel like rebooting before checking if everything works, opening the program you're using as an administrator often works as well. But you'll always need to open as an admin until you reboot so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2013 you need to add this to the `Environment Variables` and then `Restart` your pc. This is the path where .dll file located in.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I have had numerous problems with opencv and only succeded after a gruesome 4-6 months. This is the last problem I have had, but all of the above didn't work. What worked for me was just copying and pasting the opencv_core2*.dll (and opencv_highgui2*.dll which it will ask for since you included this as well) into the release (or debug folder - I'm assuming. Haven't tested this) folder of your project, where your application file is.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you figure out why updating the Environment Path variable didn't help ?

Comment: I guess it was because you 1. did not restart the application after updating the path and/or 2. the path variable did not contain the folder with the dlls. You must make sure that the bin folder you point to contains the dlls, and it must be the correct version of the dlls that the linker linked against.

Comment: You spent 4-6 months just working on opencv?!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the folder of the needed dll file (or files) to your system "Environment Variables" in "Path".
Your problem will 100% be resolved. I had this problem too.

Answer (score 2):

just open the bin folder and copy and paste the .dll files to the folder you are working in..it should fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

As to @Marc's answer, I don't think VC uses the path from the OS. Did you add the path to VC's library paths. I usually add the DLLs to the project and copy if newer on the build and that works very well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the opencv_core248 and other dlls in `opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin` folder. Just copy the dlls you require into system32 folder, and your app should start working in a flash.

Answer (score 0):

This might be like resurrecting a dead horse. But just so it's out there, the reason why the answer to these types of questions to simply put dll's into the system32 folder is because that folder is in the os's system path.

It's actually best practice to provide the os with a path link.

With windows 10

1. open up file explorer
2. right click on "this pc" and select "properties"
3. Now in the "Control Panel\System and Security\System" window that comes up, click on "Advanced System Settings" from the left hand panel.
4. At the bottom of the next window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
5. On the next window, there are two panels, the top one is for modifying variables to the current user, and the bottom panel is for modifying variables to the system. On the bottom panel, find the variable "Path" and click it to select it, then click on the "edit" button.
6. Here you can then create, edit, delete, or update the different paths for the system. For example, to add mingw32-make to the system so you can access that command via command prompt, click new, then paste in the path to the bin. Example path, "D:\Qt\Tools\mingw730_64\bin", no quotation marks nor additional whitespaces.
7. Click ok on all the windows so that the changes are saved, then **reboot** your computer for the changes to be loaded.

Answer (score -1):

The ".a" at the end of your DLL files is a problem, and those are there because you didn't use CMAKE to build OpenCV 2.0.  Additionally you do not link to the DLL files, you link to the library files, and again, the reason you do not see the correct library files is because you didn't use CMAKE to build OpenCV 2.0.  If you want to use OpenCV 2.0 you must build it for it to work correctly in Visual Studio.  If you do not want to build it then I would suggest downgrading to OpenCV 1.1pre, it comes pre-built and is much more forgiving in Visual Studio.

Another option **(and the one I would recommend)** is to abandon OpenCV and go with EmguCV.  I have been playing with OpenCV for about a year and things got much easier when I switched to EmguCV because EmguCV works with .NET, so you can use a language like C# that does not come with all the C++ baggage of pointers, header files, and memory allocation problem.

And as for the question of 64bit vs. 32bit, OpenCV does not officially support 64bit.  To be on the safe side open your project properties and change the "Platform Target" under the "Build" tab from "Any CPU" to "X86".  This should be done any time you do anything with OpenCV, even if you are using a wrapper like EmguCV.

Answer (score -3):

Copy all .dll from /bin in System32

Answer (score -3):

Just copy the .dll files to C:\windows\system32\