# OpenCV missing files after extraction?

Tags: c++, windows, opencv

I downloaded the windows binaries from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.4.5/OpenCV-2.4.5.exe/download). When i try to run a hello world program i found online, i get a missing header error. So i looked in the folder (opencv2) and only found a single header called opencv...

I found the missing headers in the module folder so i manually copied the ones i need to opencv2.. but then i got linker errors like (unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseImage referenced in function _main)

What am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The include files are here in below path `opencvinstalledDir/opencv/build/include`  `opencvinstalledDir/opencv/build/include/opencv` and  `opencvinstalledDir/opencv/build/include/opencv2` .

Please check this..

After installing opencv, set the environmental variable of the bin directory.

Comment: Thanks that did it.. I had to consult these two links for info on how to set library dependencies if anyone's interested:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10901905/installing-opencv-2-4-3-in-visual-c-2010-express
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2694994/opencv-dll-missing-but-its-not